# Using overlay feature much like a shift

Tags: keyboard, xkb

Using XKB, how could I make the keyboard send the keysym `<RTRN>` when I press `Ctrl-J`? The goal is to make sure that every program recognizes this key combination.

I know there are overlays. But the only comprehensive example I found was with a key (as in NumLock) enabling and locking the overlay feature, thereby changing the keysyms of the keys with overlay until that special key (NumLock) is pressed again.

In the particular situation, Ctrl should activate overlay only as long as it is pressed (behaving in relation to NumLock, as Shift relates to ShiftLock). This is especially problematic because when `Ctrl-J` is pressed, it should not send `Ctrl-<RTRN>` but should just send `<RTRN>`.

Of course, Ctrl should continue behaving like a Ctrl with every other key combination.

Can you tell me how this can be done?